# How to use parallelism to improve performance of my code? (tried a few things)

Tags: c++, multithreading, iterator, combinations

So here is the problem: I have a vector of custom objects and I need to compute some stuff with each unique combination of objects in the vector, and if the result is a certain value, I need to build a 2-way associative list. Here is what I've done sequentially and it works:

```
#include <itertools/combinations.hpp> //I'm using cppitertools library (installed through vcpkg)

class MyClass{
private:
    int x;
    std::string abc;
public:
    MyClass();
    GetX();
}

...

std::vector<MyClass> _myObjects;
std::unordered_map<const MyClass*, std::vector<const MyClass*>> _relationships;//list all other objects in relation with a specific object, based on custom computation on all possible combination

...
int ComputeRelation(const MyObject* obj0, const MyObject* obj1){
    //some random stuff
    return obj0->GetX() + obj1->GetX();
}
...

void BuildRelationship(){
    for(auto& combination : iter::Combination(_myObject,2)){
        //combination is a pair of MyObject
        if(ComputeRelation(combination[0],combination[1]) == 1){
            //build 2-way associative list
            _relationships[combination[0]].push_back(combination[1]);
            _relationships[combination[1]].push_back(combination[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

I originally had references everywhere instead of pointers, but the unordered_map throws an error when using references.

Now, this works fine but I would like to speed it up by parallelizing the loop since the number of combinations can get very big very quickly (**500 billions combinations** for a dataset of 1 million objects)

Here is what I have tried:

- std::for_each with parallel execution policy: I get a `Parallel algorithms require forward iterators or stronger` error --> I don't have control over the iterator type since I get it from the cppitertools library
- taskflow.for_each (from the cpptaskflow library): Inconsistent results. At first I thought it was due to concurrent access to `_relationships`, so I tried with a mutex but same result, so I think it's again something to do with the iterator type.
- Also tried transform/reduce, but I get the same problem as std::for_each

I didn't find a way to trivially split the combination set without having to first pushing all combinations into another container (which I think is inefficient)

I feel like I'm missing some obvious, easy way to do this but my brain is a bit stuck.

Thanks!

Edit:
I initially wanted to just keep a map with all the results of `ComputeRelation`, but with 500 billions elements, I was reaching insane amount of RAM usage (>>100G), that's why I decided to keep only relations that have a specific value of interest

Update #1:
So I think I found a workaround. I added a member property to MyClass that acts as an ID or key. I used a simple hashing library to hash some property of my class (converts a string to int). Then, instead of building containers of pointers, I build containers of int and use the hash value to retrieve the actual object from a map when needed, like this:

```
#include <itertools/combinations.hpp> //I'm using cppitertools library (installed through vcpkg)

class MyClass{
private:
    int x;
    std::string abc;
    uint64_t hash;
public:
    MyClass(int x, string abc){
        this.hash=SomeHashFn(abc);
    };
    GetX();
}

...

std::vector<uint64_t> _myHashes;//keeps order and duplicates
std::unordered_map<uint64_t, MyObject> _myObjects;
std::unordered_map<uint64_t, std::vector<uint64_t>> _relationships;//list all other objects in relation with a specific object, based on custom computation on all possible combinations

...
int ComputeRelation(const MyObject& obj0, const MyObject& obj1){
    //some random stuff
    return obj0.GetX() + obj1.GetX();
}
...

void BuildRelationship(){
    auto combinations = iter::Combination(_myHashes,2);
    std::for_each(std::execution::par, combinations.begin(), combinations.end(), [&](auto combination){
        //combination is a pair of hash
        MyObject obj0=_myObjects[combination[0]];
        MyObject obj1=_myObjects[combination[1]];
        if(ComputeRelation(obj0, obj1) == 1){
            //build 2-way associative list using hashes
            _relationships[combination[0]].push_back(combination[1]);
            _relationships[combination[1]].push_back(combination[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Update #2:
Never mind Update#1, I still can't process the combinations in parallel due to the iterator that `iter::Combination` return (I need forward or stronger for `std::for_each`). So I tried creating a vector with all combinations, but again ran into RAM issues. A quick calculation told me I would need approximately 80Gb just to store this vector.

Comment: Do you really need `_relationships` in one giant map? What do you do with it afterwards?

Comment: I use the the map to check if object X is in relationship with Y (a lot of time) and to find n-degree relationships (like walking through a graph, steps between required between 2 objects)

Answer (score 0):

Because your combination generator works in place, and returns a reference to the computed combination, you'll need to make copies of the combinations in order to allow for multiple threads to process them simultaneously.

One way to allow that, with a minimal change to your code, is to run thru and generate a fixed number of combinations (1000, 65536, 1000000), while storing those in some container (say, a vector that you've preallocated by calling `reserve`). Then you can use `for_each` or some other parallelization method to process that group. When the group processing is done, you loop around, build the next group (into the already allocated vector), and repeat until you've processed all of your combinations.

That won't make full use of concurrency. To get close to full concurrency, you'll likely need to get into more complicated code, possibly manually managing the threads. For instance, you can have one thread generate the combinations and pass them out to worker threads, or have each worker thread call to a shared combination generator that would pass back each combination (it would need to be protected with synchronization, and could be a potential bottleneck).

A simpler implementation may be possible, depending on how much processing each combination takes. it may be sufficient to have two threads, one that generates combinations and another that processes them. This would use two stored combinations and switch between them (one being written to, the other being read).

Comment: Thanks, I think fixed chunk could provide some efficiency if run in parallel. I still have to lock `_relationships` while each thread updates it. I will try it and report the result

Answer (score 0):

1. `std::unordered_map` is probably very slow (it is in most implementations available today). Try another container, e.g. [`dense_hash_map`](http://goog-sparsehash.sourceforge.net/doc/dense_hash_map.html).
2. You can "shard" the resulting map by some property of the key. For example, given a key of type `MyClass*`, you could hash the pointer value and use `hash % n`, where `n` is the number of shards, as the index into the vector of sub-maps. Then you will be able to fill `n` sub-maps in `n` parallel threads (ideally `n` = number of available processors).
   The downside is that the lookup becomes a little more complex - you need to compute `hash % n` during lookup as well. You can play with the hash function to find the best balance between performance and uniformity. For example, `(uintptr_t)key >> 4` could be a good enough yet very fast hash function.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I will definitely look into dense_hash_map.

Comment: `dense_hash_map` according to the documentation "can use significantly more space than other hash-map implementations". The question already complains about the space required. If anything, you'd want a space-optimized version.